# Trouble passing json data from Swift to Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, swift

I am trying to give my URL post requests bodies in Swift. Everything appears to be working well on the Swift side, but I am not seeing it in Node.js.

Swift function to create URL:

```
func composeURL_Request(path: String, queryDict: [String:String], method: String? = nil, body: [String: Any]? = nil) -> URLRequest {
    var components = URLComponents()

    components.scheme = "http"
    components.host = "localhost"
    components.port = 4001

    components.path = path
    components.setQueryItems(with: queryDict)

    var request = URLRequest(url: components.url!)

    // optional components
    if !(method == nil) {
        request.httpMethod = method
    }

    if !(body == nil) {

        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body!, options: .prettyPrinted)
            request.httpBody = jsonData
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    return request
}
```

This function does not print anything in the `catch`, so I assume it is working fine.

And then with Node.js, I am able to print out the correct query params, but printing out the body outputs `{}`. Node.js code:

```
app.post("/host", (req, res) => {
    const userID = req.query.userID;
    const eventID = req.query.eventID;
    const body = req.body;
    console.log(userID)
    console.log(eventID)
    console.log(body)
})
```

EDIT:

And here is the code that calls the Swift function:

```
let url = composeURL_Request(path: "/host",
                         queryDict: ["userID": 
"erIIm5g5uQToAioCiKnOhP1griR2", "eventID": "eventID_001"],
                         method: "POST",
                         body: ["invited": 
["Ax8Fx44T1sZAHUiTwyHRANqJOm43"],
                                "description": "long event 
description. long event description. long event description",
                                "date": 1636943919175,
                                "includes image": false])
```

It looks messed up, unfortunately.

Comment: What is `jsonData` printing? `JSONSerialization` obviously isn't failing but rather returning an empty object.

Comment: There isn’t any printed error, but printing out a successful json serialization outputs “204 bytes”

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I need to specify the content-type of my `URLRequest` so that `Express` does not ignore it.

Putting this code in my function that composed the URLRequest solves the problem for the default JSON parser (`app.use(express.json()`):

```
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```